# unable to trim an object proprty inside a model class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5, asp.net-mvc-5

i have a property named ip address , and i want to trim its value before being saved to the database. my model class is :-

```
    [MetadataType(typeof(Server_Validation))]


        public partial class Server
        {
//code goes here..
```

and the metadatatype class is :-

```
public class Server_Validation
    {
  private string ip { get; set; }


[StringLength(20)]
public string IP { get {
return ip.Trim();
}
set {
ip = value;
} }
```

but currently the ip address will not be trimmed. can anyone advice ?

Comment: Isn't the `MetadataTypeAttribute` only for applying metadata to properties (in this case `StringLength`)? I don't think the property accessors in `class Server_Validation` get hit (and from examples I've seen your don't event need the them - it an be just `public string IP;`). I think this logic needs to be in `class Server`

Comment: but the problem is that the class Server is auto generated and i do not want to apply my changes directly to it , since i will loose all the modification if i re-generate the .edmx file.. and of course i can not override the IP property inside the partial class since i will get an error that IP already exists... so what is the best way to guarantee that the IP got trimmed...

Comment: Can you not just do this the controller when posting the data to your action method. Another option may be a regular expression attribute added to the property in `class Server_Validation` so spaces are invalid

Comment: doing so on the action method will require me to do the trim multiple time, i just want to do it on the model level ,, and stop worrying about it ...